# changing linked list into a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, templates, doubly-linked-list

Hi could you please help me change this linked list into a doubly linked list ? 
I would be very grateful for help :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    node<T> *next;
    node<T> *prev;
};

template <class T>
class Container
{

public:
    //constructs a new empty Kontener
    Container()
    {
        head = new node<T>;
        head->next = head;
        head->prev = head;
    };
```

//constructs a new jp_list that is a copy of an existing list

```
 Container(const Container<T>& rt_side)
    {
        head = new node<T>;
        head->next = head;
        head->prev = head;

        node<T> *crt_ptr = rt_side.head->next;
        while(crt_ptr != rt_side.head)
        {
            push_back(crt_ptr->data);
            crt_ptr = crt_ptr->next;
        }
    };

    //adds a data node to the front of the list
    void push_front(T nw_data)
    {
        node<T> *temp = new node<T>;
        temp->data = nw_data;

        temp->next = head->next;
        head->next->prev = temp;

        temp->prev = head;
        head->next = temp;
    };

    //adds a data node to the end of the list
    void push_back(T nw_data)
    {
        node<T> *temp = new node<T>;
        temp->data = nw_data;

        head->prev->next = temp;
        temp->prev = head->prev;

        temp->next = head;
        head->prev = temp;
    };

    //removes the first node and returns the data
    T pop_front()
    {
        node<T> *temp = head->next;
        T temp_data = head->next->data;

        head->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->prev = head;

        delete temp;

        return temp_data;
    };

    //removes the last node and returns the data
    T pop_back()
    {
        node<T> *temp = head->prev;
        T temp_data = head->prev->data;

        head->prev = temp->prev;
        temp->prev->next = head;

        delete temp;

        return temp_data;
    };

    //resturns the size of the list
    int size()
    {
        int size = 0;
        node<T> *crt_ptr; //pointer to current node

        crt_ptr = head->next;
        while(crt_ptr != head)
        {
            size += 1;
            crt_ptr = crt_ptr->next; //advance to the next node then loop
        }

        return size;
    };

    //prints out all the data in the list
    void display_all()
    {
        node<T> *crt_ptr = head->next;

        for(int i = 0; crt_ptr != head; i++)
        {
            cout << "Node " << (i+1) << ": " << crt_ptr->data << endl;

            crt_ptr = crt_ptr->next;
        }
    };

    Container& operator= (const Container& rt_side)
    {
        if(this == &rt_side)
            return *this;
        node<T> *crt_ptr = head->next;

        //empty this list so the rt_side can be coppied in
        while(crt_ptr != head)
        {
            crt_ptr = crt_ptr->next;
            pop_front();
        }

        crt_ptr = rt_side.head->next;

        while(crt_ptr != rt_side.head)
        {
            push_back(crt_ptr->data);
            crt_ptr = crt_ptr->next;
        }

        return *this;
    };

    virtual ~Container()
    {
        int list_size = size();

        for(int i = 0; i < list_size; i++)
        {
            pop_front();
        }

        delete head;
    };

private:
    node<T> *head;

};

#endif
```

I am just a beginner so please help me :)

Comment: `Hi could you please help me change this linked list into a doubly linked list ?`  To change something, that something has to already exist.  Where is your existing linked list class that is not doubly linked?

Comment: I know that I have to add node<T> *tail; but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @MIchaelDonson `I know that I have to add node<T> *tail`  A doubly linked list does not need this pointer, unless you want a way to get to the last element quickly.  All you need are the `next` and `prev`

Comment: BTW, your `operator=` need not be so complicated: `{Container temp = rt_side; std::swap(temp.head, head); return *this; }` This works only if your copy constructor and destructor are working correctly.

Comment: In your push_back, there are many problems. head->prev is dereferencing null (your node does not initialize prev or next pointers). Also, it is pushing front, not back.

Comment: Actually, after reading your code, it looks more like a cyclical list. Could you please clarify what kind of list you are looking for, and please fix your question.

Comment: I am looking for a doubly linked list. It is really difficult for me thanks for any answer and please help :)

Answer (score 0):

The tail would always point to the last item that was inserted into the list.

However, I do not think that having a tail pointer makes it necessarily a doubly linked list. A singly linked list can also have a tail pointer (however useless it might be). I believe you are asking to create a double ended doubly linked list.

You already have the next and previous pointers to enable the double link. All you have to do, is when you push something into the list, you need to make the tail pointer point to the node that is being added. Similarly, when removing a node, you need the tail pointer to point to tail's previous BEFORE deleting the last node.

*** UPDATE ***
Here is some code. I am assuming a double ended doubly linked list with two ends.

```
void push_front(T nw_data)
{
    node<T> *temp = new node<T>;
    temp->data = nw_data;

    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else if(head == tail)
    {
        head->next = temp;
        temp->prev = head;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = head->next;
        head->next->prev = temp;

        temp->prev = head;
        head->next = temp;        
    }        
};

//adds a data node to the end of the list
void push_back(T nw_data)
{
    node<T> *temp = new node<T>;
    temp->data = nw_data;

    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else if(head == tail)
    {
        head->next = temp;
        temp->prev = head;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->prev = tail;
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;      
    }  
};

T pop_back()
{
    node<T> *temp = tail;
    T temp_data = tail->data;

    tail = tail->prev;
    tail->next = null;

    delete temp;

    return temp_data;
};
```

*** UPDATE *** Copy Constructor
In your copy constructor, if the push_back sets the tail, then all you need to do is to push_back the nodes like you are doing. head->next = head and head->prev = head makes the linked list cyclical.

```
Container(const Container<T>& rt_side)
{
    this->head = rt_side.head;

    node<T> * crt_ptr = rt_side.head->next;

    while (crt_ptr != null)
    {
        push_back(crt_ptr->data);

        crt_ptr = crt_ptr->next;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I would be very grateful if you could help me with copy constructor and assingment operator there are the most difficult.

Comment: @MIchaelDonson - Is there something wrong with the copy constructor now?  Also, my comment above shows how to implement the assignment operator without all of that code you have now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this copy constructor but could you please explain me how should i implement assingment operator ?

Comment: So I don't have to write Node<T> *tail; in order to have a doubly linked list ?

Comment: No you don't need a tail for a doubly linked list.